# How we can generate sitemap.xml in angular dynamically

Tags: node.js, angular, sitemap

I have  provided an API(in nodejs) returns a list of products in order to add to sitemap.xml

I have a file named sitemap.xml in the src folder in my angular project.
How we can add a list of product to sitemap.xml

**URL:**

**xxx.com/sitemap.xml** (now it's empty)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">

<url>
</url>

</urlset>
```

Comment: Angular as such cannot handle this kind of task. If you have angular universal, you can add a route in your `server.ts` file to do that, otherwise have another nodejs process generate the file, using the API

Comment: @David Can you please let me know using Angular 9 how to get dynamic sitemap file at project root like websitename.com/sitemap.xml or how to fetch node generated xml file in  angular project root path ?

Comment: Just declare a route in your `server.ts` and from there return your sitemap.xml

Comment: @David Thanks for the reply. In my case angular and node project are on different path. I tried but through api call, it returns whole xml file content as string, but is there any way to fetch sitemap.xml as xml file in angular 9 root path?

Comment: Just output your string as a xml file. `res.contentType("text/xml");      res.send(yourXmlString);`